# How to work with a designer in Django without giving him full access to all the source code?

Tags: django

I hired a designer to help me with a personal project I'm doing with Django. I would like the designer could just access to the folders /templates and /static of each app. to edit .html files, style sheets and images.

I do not want to risk giving him full access to the source code.

I'm lost, How do you usually do this?

Greetings.

Comment: What is the risk of letting designer see the source code? There should be no risk if you use version control.

Comment: You did not state what you are currently using to share files for the project. This also has nothing to do with django, its a simple file permissions issue and not appropriate for stackoverflow. It would be better suited in programmers.stackoverflow.com

Comment: For example: He could resell the code in the future. What advantages does the version control about this?

Answer (score 2):

1) Get him access only to template directories (html, css). There are no secrets because anyone can view it with help of browser or other utility.

2) Use custom template tags and filters for him (http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/). In this case he couldn't view source Python code, he works with tags and filters as with black boxes.

After modifications he could test the project without reloading of Django application server.

Answer (score 2):

Hire a designer who doesn't strike you as dishonest.

Otherwise, provide him access only to templates, css, image, and other static content, and document what is available in each template's context. Let him ask for anything else he needs in the context, and if necessary provide him with custom tags.

Answer (score 0):

as noted, this doesn't have much to do with django and may be best asked elsewhere.

it depends on how you store/share your code currently.

if you use some version control system, i guess you'd have to create a separate repository for the stuff you want to share. if you use e.g. git (the one i'm most familiar with), have a look at [submodules](http://book.git-scm.com/5_submodules.html)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can just have him build the design as flat files and retrofit it into your environment after fact (go through and add the templatetags and filters, etc) internally.